# Comparing like words between two dictionaries

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I am using python 3.x,

I have 2 dictionaries (both very large but will substitute here). The values of the dictionaries contain more than one word:

```
dict_a = {'key1': 'Large left panel', 'key2': 'Orange bear rug', 'key3': 'Luxo jr. lamp'}
dict_a

{'key1': 'Large left panel',
 'key2': 'Orange bear rug',
 'key3': 'Luxo jr. lamp'}

dict_b = {'keyX': 'titanium panel', 'keyY': 'orange Ball and chain', 'keyZ': 'large bear musket'}
dict_b

{'keyX': 'titanium panel',
 'keyY': 'orange Ball and chain',
 'keyZ': 'large bear musket'}
```

I am looking for a way to compare the individual words contained in the values of `dict_a` to the words contained in the values of `dict_b` and return a dictionary or data-frame that contains the word, and the keys from `dict_a` and `dict_b` it is associated with:

My desired output (not formatted any certain way):

- bear: key2 (from dict_a), keyZ(from dict_b)
- Luxo: key3
- orange: key2 (from dict_a), keyY (from dict_b)

I've got code that works for looking up a specific word in a single dictionary but it's not sufficient for what I need to accomplish here:

```
def search(myDict, lookup):
    aDict = {}
    for key, value in myDict.items():
        for v in value:
            if lookup in v:
               aDict[key] = value
    return aDict
    print (key, value)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dicts = {'a': {'key1': 'Large left panel', 'key2': 'Orange bear rug', 
               'key3': 'Luxo jr. lamp'},
         'b': {'keyX': 'titanium panel', 'keyY': 'orange Ball and chain', 
               'keyZ': 'large bear musket'} }
from collections import defaultdict
index = defaultdict(list)
for dname, d in dicts.items():
    for key, words in d.items():
        for word in words.lower().split(): # lower() to make Orange/orange match
            index[word].append((dname, key))
```

`index` now contains:

```
{'and'     : [('b', 'keyY')],
 'ball'    : [('b', 'keyY')],
 'bear'    : [('a', 'key2'), ('b', 'keyZ')],
 'chain'   : [('b', 'keyY')],
 'jr.'     : [('a', 'key3')],
 'lamp'    : [('a', 'key3')],
 'large'   : [('a', 'key1'), ('b', 'keyZ')],
 'left'    : [('a', 'key1')],
 'luxo'    : [('a', 'key3')],
 'musket'  : [('b', 'keyZ')],
 'orange'  : [('a', 'key2'), ('b', 'keyY')],
 'panel'   : [('a', 'key1'), ('b', 'keyX')],
 'rug'     : [('a', 'key2')],
 'titanium': [('b', 'keyX')] }
```

---

### Update to comments

Since your actual dictionary is a mapping from string to list (and not string to string) change your loops to

```
for dname, d in dicts.items():
    for key, wordlist in d.items():    # changed "words" to "wordlist"
        for words in wordlist:         # added extra loop to iterate over wordlist
            for word in words.split(): # removed .lower() since text is always uppercase
                index[word].append((dname, key))
```

Since your lists have only one item you could just do

```
for dname, d in dicts.items():
    for key, wordlist in d.items(): 
        for word in wordlist[0].split(): # assumes single item list
            index[word].append((dname, key))
```

If you have words that you don't want to be added to your index you can skip adding them to the `index`:

```
words_to_skip = {'-', ';', '/', 'AND', 'TO', 'UP', 'WITH', ''}
```

Then filter them out with

```
if word in words_to_skip:
    continue
```

I noticed that you have some words surrounded by parenthesis (such as `(342)` and `(221)`).  If you want to get rid the parenthesis do

```
if word[0] == '(' and word[-1] == ')':
    word = word[1:-1]
```

Putting this all together we get

```
words_to_skip = {'-', ';', '/', 'AND', 'TO', 'UP', 'WITH', ''}
for dname, d in dicts.items():
    for key, wordlist in d.items():
        for word in wordlist[0].split():  # assumes single item list
            if word[0] == '(' and word[-1] == ')': 
                word = word[1:-1]         # remove outer parenthesis
            if word in words_to_skip:     # skip unwanted words
                continue 
            index[word].append((dname, key))
```

Comment: Thanks Steven, this is exactly what I'm looking for, though I the dictionaries I'm actually working with gave me an error:

`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'lower'`

my first `dict` looks like:

 `KEY1: ['AIRPLANE NUMBERS  - 111'],
 KEY2: ['FAA TYPE CERTIFICATION'],
 KEY3: ['TAKEOFF AND LANDING WITH TAILWIND UP TO 15-KNOTS'],`

and my second `dict` looks like:

`'keyA': ['RADAR (TXT)TRANSMTT (342)'],
 'keyB': ['T.E. FAIRINGS (221)'],
 'keyC': ['VERTICAL FIN (313)']`

Thanks again for your help! Also, I'm fairly new here so apologies for the poor formatting.

Comment: @PixarJunkie: You have your dicts as mapping from string to list and I wrote the code for mapping from string to string (`{KEY1: ['AIRPLANE NUMBERS - 111']`} vs `{KEY1: 'AIRPLANE NUMBERS - 111'}`.  In order to tell you how to fix this I have a few questions.  Is there ever more than one item in the list (ie `{'KEY1': ['AIRPLANE NUMBERS - 111', 'SOMETHING ELSE']}`?  Are your values always upper case?  `'RADAR (TXT)TRANSMTT (342).split()'` would give you the strings `['RADAR', '(TXT)TRANSMTT', '(342)']`.  Is that okay or did you want something like `['RADAR', 'TXT', 'TRANSMIT', '342']`?

Comment: Rumbaski: Yes I didn't realize that either until the error, sorry!

There is never more than one item in a list, though there are `- ; /` and  other various notations throughout. 

Everything is upper case with no exceptions.

The first case would work just fine as splitting the `(TXT)` from `TRNASMTT` would return some unrelated results.

Comment: @PixarJunkie: Updated my answer.

Comment: @ Steven Rumbalski: Thanks this works perfectly! I was curious about one more thing... :) If I wanted to wanted to add `word` to `index` only if it showed up in BOTH `dicts` what would that look like? I tried `if word in {'a'} and word in {'b'}: ` before `index[word].append((dname, key))` but it returned an empty list. Thanks again, really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want pretty easily. This code produces output in the format `{word: {key: name_of_dict_the_key_is_in}}`:

```
def search(**dicts):
    result = {}

    for name, dct in dicts.items():
        for key, value in dct.items():
            for word in value.split():
                result.setdefault(word, {})[key] = name

    return result
```

You call it with the input dictionaries as keyword arguments. The keyword you use for each dictionary will be the string used to describe it in the output dictionary, so use something like `search(dict_a=dict_a, dict_b=dict_b)`.

If your dictionaries might have some of the same keys, this code might not work right, since the keys could collide if they have the same words in their values. You could make the outer dict contain a list of `(key, name)` tuples, instead of an inner dictionary, I suppose. Just change the assignment line to `result.setdefault(word, []).append((key, name))`. That would be less handy to search in though.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght! I got a similar error `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'` that I got using Stevens solution above so I think there's some additional formatting I need to do for my particular dictionaries.

Comment: Ah, it seems the dictionaries you're passing in have lists as values, not plain strings. If there's always just one string in the list, you could do `value[0].split()`, otherwise you might need to add an extra loop to go over the list items and split each of them (assuming you do actually want to split by word, like you implied in the question).